# Unexpected response from OpenTok

Tags: javascript, opentok, tokbox

Calling **opentok.startArchive** for two requests of mine. Both have valid room name values which are given for this method. Thus, I do not think that it is because of my request.

One error indicates that **"Unexpected response from OpenTok"**, another error in the successful part. Not sure what specifically the problem is. `JSON.stringify(err)` gives me that much details. Any ideas how I can dig in?

```
router.post('/startArchive', function (req, res, next) {

......
........
}).then(function (sessionId) { 
  console.log("#start_archive")
  opentok.startArchive(sessionId, {
    name: roomName,
    outputMode: "individual" //composed
}, function (err, archive) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("opentok error")
    res.json(err);
    res.end();
    return console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
  }
  else{
    /*SUCCESSFULL*/
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two major things to start an archive:

- the session type has to be `routed` (https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/create-session/)
- the session at least has one connection (https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/archiving/)

You can also check the validity of your account. Perhaps it's inactive?

Comment: My account is active and it works fine when I open a new session for my conference.  

The question would be to ask if it is right approach to generate new session for each conference?  OR Should I use a static session id per person, and use it each time he opens a conference?  

What do you suggest?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem while using the outputMode: 'individual'
My session are routed and there is one connection. Working with `composed` but when i put `outputMode: 'individual'`, i reproduce the same crash as @shamaleyte